# How to use removeRows with QStringListModel

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qstringlistmodel

I have a QStringListModel which works ok, but then I need to delete all the rows from it **from QML**.

I would expect removeRowsfunction from Qt documentation work like that, but I don't know how to use it property.

```
removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex())
```

I tried to use it like this:

```
myModel.removeRows(1, 1)
```

But I am getting thie error:

```
qrc:/Logger.qml:63: TypeError: Property 'removeRows' of object QStringListModel(0x337350) is not a function
```

Can someone explain how to use removeRows correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`removeRows()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html#removeRows) is not invokable from QML. the solution is to make it invokable by creating a new class and overriding that method:

```
class StringListModel: public QStringListModel{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()){
        return QStringListModel::removeRows(row, count, parent);
    }
};
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/46367568-how-to-use-removerows-with-qstringlistmodel) there is an example.

Comment: What is the rationale behind having to do this instead of the Qt library adding the `Q_INVOKABLE` flag to the `QStringListModel`? Is it an oversight or is there some reason why we shouldn't be deleting items from QML?